# Compare old password against an active directory using LDAP Spring

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap

I have created an endpoint to update the password of the user that is inside our Active Directory
using LDAP Spring.
I have no problem changing it without checking if the previous password matches, but I need to somehow check that the previous password is the same as the one currently in the active directory.

My code is giving me this error right now:

```
LDAP: error code 19 - 0000216C: AtrErr: DSID-03190F1E, 
#1:\n\t0: 0000216C: DSID-03190F1E, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 9005a (unicodePwd)
```

My password update code is as follows:

```
public void updateUserPassword(User user,String oldPassword, String newPassword) throws NameNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Attribute oldattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", toUnicodeBytes(oldPassword);
    Attribute newattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", toUnicodeBytes(newPassword);
    ModificationItem olditem = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, oldattr);
    ModificationItem newitem = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, newattr);
    ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(buildDn(user), new ModificationItem[] { olditem, newitem });
}

public static byte[] toUnicodeBytes(String password){
    String quotedPassword = "\"" + password + "\"";
    char unicodePwd[] = quotedPassword.toCharArray();
    byte pwdArray[] = new byte[unicodePwd.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < unicodePwd.length; i++)
    {
        pwdArray[i * 2 + 1] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] >>> 8);
        pwdArray[i * 2 + 0] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] & 0xff);
    }
    return pwdArray;
}
```

The following code works, but I want to verify that the previous password is correct, so I can't use it.

```
public void updateUserPassword(User user,String oldPassword, String newPassword) throws NameNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Attribute attr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd",toUnicodeBytes(newPassword));
    ModificationItem item = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, attr);
    ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(buildDn(user), new ModificationItem[] { item });
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the user you're testing with actually have permission to change their own password?

Comment: yes, it's the admin user.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your issue since you say resetting the password works, but it's worth mentioning:

To change or reset a password, the connection must be secure. Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2).

You can do this by connecting to port 636, which is the default LDAPS port (LDAP over SSL). This can be done by specifying the port in the LDAP connection string, e.g. `"LDAP://example.com:636"`. Some LDAP libraries may support using `"LDAPS://example.com"` to achieve the same thing.

Since some servers use a self-signed cert, which won't be trusted by default. So you may run into issues with that. But search for "Java LDAPS" for help in making that work, if you need.

Comment: I'm using ldaps for the whole process, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: could it be the password policies?

Comment: @Rusty23 It's possible